# Selenium Grid + Python: clicking on a WebElement results very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have built a bot that plays an online roulette with Selenium (Selenium Grid) and Python.
When it comes to clicking on the number I want to bet on, it is extremely slow and does not manage to complete its stake (within the given time range for the bet) across all numbers that make my bet complete.

It seems like slowness may be given from the animation the button does after I click on it.

The code is very simple:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)) # I manage to retrieve the WebElement, this is fast, no problem here
element.click() # this is slow
```

Here you can find:

- how it looks now > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEuWTtrXHzRfXXVHhUbdNR8XtgMeWdU-/view?usp=sharing
- my target > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUbr6rpOGjdMuClD5hby91jPVumqwLC5/view?usp=sharing (here I use the pynput library which is not my target cause I want the script to run on the server using Selenium Grid).

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure, is it the same problem or not. In my case, after clicking submit button on login form and redirecting to home page, my script doesn't do anything for around 4 minutes.

I've noticed, that `WebElement.click()` function ends execution only after page stops loading, but some trackers on site prevent page from complete loading, so I added uBlock extension and got rid of my problem.